# UIPickerView and UIDatePicker are not responding to interaction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I have a UITextField in a UITableView. I am trying to have a UIPickerView or a UIDatePicker as its input view. Both options are appearing and in case of UIPickerView, it is loading correct data. The problem is that it is not scrollable and user cannot interact with it, choose and scroll between the various options.

Userinteraction is set to yes, delegates are correct and everything is in place.

This is the code:

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UIDatePicker *datepicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [datepicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];

    textField.inputView = datepicker;

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you set the `inputView` in this method?
Do this in `viewDidLoad`. This is a configuration,
doesn't make sense set a particular `inputView` each time the user focus on that `textField`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(editTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [textField setInputView:datePicker];
}
```

and then:

```
- (void)editTextField:(id)sender
{
    UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker *)textField.inputView;
    [picker setMaximumDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSDate *eventDate = picker.date;
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:eventDate];
    textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dateString];
}
```

Comment: the UITextField is in a table view, it is loaded dynamically, thus I can't assign the input view in the viewdidload method.

Comment: It is the same, you should to have a custom cell class, and put that code in his init method, or when you configure the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: I tried your approach, but still it is not working.. Plus the years field are not showing up correctly

Comment: I tried putting initializing both pickers in viewdidload method, but still it is not working.. And I can;t find any answer on the internet in any forum